# a mail rule that involve calendar

Tags: email, automation, calendar, applescript, rules

I would like to make a rule in Mail Mac that says : **if** an e-mail is received from this group of people (from the app contacts) **and** the event named WORK on the app calendar **is not** on, **then** send this automatic message.

The automatic message (kind of « out of office ») is easy on Mail Mac… but it’s not possible to add a condition from calendar. So I thought that adding an AppleScript code could work… but I am not sure it’s the best way and I don’t know how to do.

It’s a tricky rule. Do you know if there’s a way to do that ?

Comment: I've never tried sending an email via AppleScript, sounds like a potential Lovebug, if contacts can be accessed, but apart from that, what you describe sounds doable. An AppleScript action for mail rule, retrieving information from the Calendar app is not easy but possible, then sending the automatic message.

Comment: Oh sorry. I was not very clear so I edited my question that was more : if an e-mail is received from this group of people (from the app contacts) and the event named WORK on the app calendar is not on, then send this automatic message.